# Image URL from another website not loading

Tags: html, image, url, loading

I want to show some shoes on my website, to do so I wrote the following code :

```
<img src="https://8512ea0a.nuajik.io/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/540x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/0/0/001364038_001.jpg" alt='Some shoes'>
```

this is what i have when loading the page. The little pop-up says "Impossible to load image" : 
[image not loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEySA.png)

And what I see in the page is the alternative text "Some shoes".

I have no clue why this is not working. I tried to add the image with CSS, Javascript, none of it worked.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> %  curl -I -e "http://example.com" "https://8512ea0a.nuajik.io/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/540x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/0/0/001364038_001.jpg"
> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
> %  curl -I  "https://8512ea0a.nuajik.io/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/540x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/0/0/001364038_001.jpg"
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> ```

The server hosting the image pays attention to the *referer* header sent by the browser. If the site trying to display the image isn't on a whitelist, it returns a 403 Forbidden response.

It looks like you've found an image on another website and are trying to violate their copyright while simultaneously making use of their bandwidth to enhance your own site.

They have taken steps to prevent you from doing that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Quentin ! Can i know where to find this information about the code returned by the URL call ? Could be usefull :) 
So the only way is to contact the website and to be on the whitelist ?

Comment: Thanks Quentin but that wasn't my question. Sorry I don't have a fluent English. What I wanted to know was what did you use to have the result of the request sent by the URL ?